# How to create an Angular Domain Model correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop

I want to create a domain model correctly.

My attempt below creates the properties outside the constructor.
Should I be creating and setting the properties of the TestModel class inside the constructor only? this way their would be less lines of code

I have the below attempt that I think is correct:

```
export class TestModel1 {
  public currentPage: number = 0;
  public hasNext: boolean = false;
  public hasPrev: boolean = false;
  public pageSize: number = 0;
  public totalItems: number = 0;

  constructor(data: any) {
      this.currentPage = data.currentPage;
      this.hasNext = data.hasNext;
      this.hasPrev = data.hasPrev;
      this.pageSize = data.pageSize;
      this.totalItems = data.totalItems;
  }
}
```

It just seems a little big, too many lines of code.

Currently I need to pass in a data object and then map.
Is their a clever way for me to implement this better using the constructor function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we speak about the model class, the declaration of that should be like in example below:

```js
export class Account {
    constructor(
        public activated: boolean,
        public authorities: string[],
        public email: string,
        public firstName: string,
        public langKey: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public login: string,
        public imageUrl: string
    ) {}
}
```

Certainly you should not to define values outside of constructor. You may do declare the model class members as you have in your example, but without the definition of values:

```js
export class TestModel1 {
  public currentPage: number;
  public hasNext: boolean;
  public hasPrev: boolean;
  public pageSize: number;
  public totalItems: number;

  constructor(data: any = null) {
    if(data !== null) {
      this.currentPage = data.currentPage;
      this.hasNext = data.hasNext;
      this.hasPrev = data.hasPrev;
      this.pageSize = data.pageSize;
      this.totalItems = data.totalItems;
    }
  }
}
```

And if you want to declare default values, my advice is to do this inside the constructor for clean and good code.

**Update:**

```js
export class TestModel1 {
  public currentPage: number;
  public hasNext: boolean;
  public hasPrev: boolean;
  public pageSize: number;
  public totalItems: number;

  constructor(data: any = null) {
    if(data !== null) {
      this.currentPage = data.currentPage;
      this.hasNext = data.hasNext;
      this.hasPrev = data.hasPrev;
      this.pageSize = data.pageSize;
      this.totalItems = data.totalItems;
    }
    else {
      this.currentPage = 0;
      this.hasNext = false;
      this.hasPrev = false;
      this.pageSize = 0;
      this.totalItems = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

That's would be better, if you want to have defaults

Comment: For my example I do: new TestModel1(data);
Then set the data properties of the class.

Comment: So what your saying is I did it correct, but just don't set the default values of the properties?

Comment: @AngularM this is the right way to do it. But if you want to have some defaults, you also may to add else cause in your constructor and set the defaults there.

Comment: @AngularM yes, that's what i mean :)

Comment: May be should be better instead data: any = null using an interface so you can do data: TestInterface

Comment: @Whisher for the complete model as model->view-entity that's would be better as well, yes

Comment: What I don't like is the fact that I have a property inside and outside of the constructor. The problem is I have too many properties for this class. So I have to pass in a data object and then map them. I would like to declare the properties and set them inside the constructor. Could you show me if this is possible?

Comment: I've edited my example above, let me know if theirs a better way

Comment: @AngularM I have updated my answer, see bellow. That would be a better way to set defaults using constructor. When you will call the constructor with null data it would set defaults then

Comment: @AngularM and one more thing is - if you do not want to have class properties outside the constructor and have a shortly code - you may use the forst code example from my answer and do all inside the constructor like in the last example :)

Comment: @AngularM if you are sure that you will not call the class constructor without data, you may to remove else cause :) it's really depends on your implementation. In that case use just first one code example

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see in the question is that of *duplication*. All of the properties are duplicated in the constructor, which violates the DRY principle of clean code.

If you want to populate a new instance of your domain object in a more concise way, you can do the following:

```
export class TestModel1 {
  public currentPage: number;
  public hasNext: boolean;
  public hasPrev: boolean;
  public pageSize: number;
  public totalItems: number;

  constructor(data: any) {
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
         this[key] = data[key]
      });
  }
}
```

You have to ensure that the input data object will have the correct properties only, which may or may not be easy, based on the source of data.